# Azkaban project name rename

Tags: hadoop, scheduler, azkaban

I am running an Azkaban executor and web application. I have created a new project using the web interface. I tried to change its name by changing the `name` column in the `projects` table in the database. But still, the web UI is showing the old name for the project.

How can I change the name of the project in Azkaban?